# Python: Process lines from csv file with pandas

Tags: python, io, pandas

I have a file with 230K lines where I have 2 integers separated by space. I read the whole file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
```

However, I need to process each line of this file, so I do this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
     processLine(df['X.1'][i], df['X.2'][i])
```

Unfortunately, this results in as twice much time as in naive approach:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        processLine(map(int,line.split()))
```

Is there better way to process through all lines with *pandas*?

Comment: Can you show us what `processLine` actually does, otherwise you could do `df.apply(processLine(row), axis=1)` and within `processLine(i)` handle the passed row appropriately like `processLine(i):  return doSomething(i.1) + doSomething(x.2)`

Comment: processLine just creates an object and append this object to list. What is supposed to be in row variable in your comment?

Comment: `row` will be that row as we iterate over the `df` think of it as equivalent to `df.iloc[i]`, my point is that this should be quicker but if you showed us what `processLine` does we could suggest a better method